# Stack smashing detected after destrutor of sf::RenderWindow

Tags: c++, destructor, sfml, stack-smash

My code look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main(){
    sf::RenderWindow window( sf::VideoMode(800,600), "title");
    std::cout<<"123"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

which prints on consol:

```
Setting vertical sync not supported
123
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

It means that problem occurs while destructor of sf::RenderWindow is called.
I am using `-lsfml-system -lsfml-window -lsfml-graphics` to compile.

Can you tell what might be the problem?

Comment: Is that the exact code you have? Nothing more?

Comment: nothing, I know it's weird.
What I can tell more is that I use Linux

Comment: Try to set up a simple event loop, like [here](https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=24107.0) to see if something changes.

Comment: When I do so, it shows window correctly, but console still prints the same output

Comment: This is not caused by the destructor.  You smash the stack by creating an sf::RenderWindow object that is larger than the compiler thought it was.  In other words, the version of sf you linked is not the same as the version you #included.

Comment: That might be it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hans Passant was correct in the comments.

I was experiencing a similar issue. Turned out I had CSFML 2.4.0 and SFML 2.4.0 installed.

Installing SFML 2.5.1 fixed the issue.